# Jenkins Pipeline on openshift

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, openshift

[error details e](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VK1A.jpg)

Hi,

I’m deploying my project on openshift using groovy Jenkins. For the openshift cluster 3.9 I were able to deploy successfully but then my client decided to move to openshift cluster 3.11, I were given the new configure with cluster name and token by the CI team, of course I don’t have full permission on the cluster. So when I changed to the new URL, cluster name and token, I always get the error message as  “Rolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io is forbidden: User system:serviceaccount:abc:jenkins can not list in rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io in namespace ‘projectname’: no RABC match”. I have checked using oc command line to check who can deploy and the system:serviceaccount:abc:jenkins is not list  under my project namespace. I have requested to the CI person and they said it’s not the permission issue it relates to the cluster configure.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a service account to give itself a rolebinding but the service account does not have permission to do so.

Check permission of the service account:

```
kubectl auth can-i list rolebindings -n projectname --as=system:serviceaccount:abc:jenkins
no
```

A cluster admin need to run below commands to give the service account permission:

```
$ oc policy add-role-to-user edit system:serviceaccount:abc:jenkins \
    -n projectname
$ oc policy add-role-to-user system:image-puller system:serviceaccounts:abc:jenkins \
    -n projectname
```

Comment: Thanks. That is what trying to tell the CI person, but they still insist something wrong with my code about the cluster mismatch. They said the abc service account is the admin user of my project, so the issue doesn't relate to the permission. But it obviously relates to the permission issue.

Comment: you can run the kubectl auth can-i command as in my answer and take that to the CI team as a proof.

Comment: Thanks. Just another question, is the service account associated with the cluster name and token that I was given? Sorry I'm new to openshift and Kubernetes.  As every time I do a build on Jenkins, it always associates with that "abc:jenkins" service account